# Script en global.asax para redirigir páginas

Tags: asp.net

Tengo unas páginas aspx para pc y otras para móviles.

Si el dispositivo es un móvil, redirijo a versión móviles.

En global.asax tengo

```
    Sub Session_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice Then
        Dim blnpaginamovil As Boolean = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.StartsWith("Respequena", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        'palabras de comienzo del path
        If Not blnpaginamovil Then
            'nuevo path -mal, no sé cómo averiguar el path actual-
            'el redirect debería ser Respequena/Cresolia/default.aspx?idioma=<%=IIf(Request.QueryString("idioma") IsNot Nothing, Request.QueryString("idioma"), 1)%>
            'o Respequena/Ocio/default.aspx?idioma=<%=IIf(Request.QueryString("idioma") IsNot Nothing, Request.QueryString("idioma"), 1)%>
            'en función de si en el path original está Ocio o Cresolia
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Respequena")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

No sé cómo obtener la dirección actual de las páginas. Se redirigirá a Respequna/Cresolia o Respequena/Ocio en función de si en la dirección actual está Cresolia u Ocio.

¿Sabéis cómo se hace el script?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El global.asax lo tengo ahora

```
    Sub Session_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice Then
        Dim blnpaginamovil As Boolean = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.StartsWith("Respequena", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        'palabras de comienzo del path
        If Not blnpaginamovil Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Respequena/" & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

¿Está bien para obtener la versión móvil (Respequena) de las páginas web?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, puedes usar [edit]  tu pregunta y añadirlo